# Is there a way to have URL-related CSS-Styles?

Tags: html, css, url, styles, href

Is there a way to have URL-related CSS-Styles?

For example. I have a link on my webpage

```
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>
```

after clicking the URL changes to **test.com#blue**

Is it possible to apply style depending on this URL?

```
background-color: blue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [the `:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo) which will match elements with an `id` that matches the fragment identifier in the URL.